# Running Webdriver from tomcat java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run a Java webapp hosted on tomcat that will run selenium / chrome web driver.

However when you try to launch the chromedriver you get a 500 internal server error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:137)

I've tried multiple variants to load the drivers as well as changing to firefoxdriver and RemoteWebDriver but i still get the same issue.

I have placed the chromeDriver and Chrome.exe within web pages/web-inf/lib.
Also System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver.exe");

But nothing changes.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to specify the full page to the chromedriver including the `.exe` extension.

Answer (score 0):

It was a terrible challenge for me the find a *fully working* combination of these two artifacts

- selenium-chrome-driver
- Google guava (which includes com.google.common.base.*)

I finally manage to get a working one:

- selenium 3.12.0
- guava 21.0

## webdrivers.xml

```
 <root>
        <windows>
             <driver id="googlechrome">
                <version id="2.35">
                    <bitrate thirtytwobit="true" sixtyfourbit="true">
                        <filelocation>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_win32.zip</filelocation>
                        <hash>c787c0b36fbf8ea3325df386c0c3c41d3f681b4b</hash>
                        <hashtype>sha1</hashtype>
                    </bitrate>
                </version>
            </driver>
        </windows>
        <linux>
            <driver id="googlechrome">
                <version id="2.35">
                    <bitrate sixtyfourbit="true">
                        <filelocation>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_linux64.zip</filelocation>
                        <hash>ccc980e3b0b74f0d067f1d3e89d9cc81b8a6b2aa</hash>
                        <hashtype>sha1</hashtype>
                    </bitrate>
                </version>
            </driver>
        </linux>
        <osx>
            <driver id="googlechrome">              
                <version id="2.36">
                    <bitrate sixtyfourbit="true">
                        <filelocation>https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/chromedriver_mac64.zip</filelocation>
                        <hash>28b58747bbb4b4591ff939a692f8755a11428550</hash>
                        <hashtype>sha1</hashtype>
                    </bitrate>
                </version>            
            </driver>        
        </osx>
    </root>
```

Comment: I also suggest you to put the *absolute* path of the driver
if  (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC) {
   String fullpath = new File("webdrivers/osx/googlechrome/64bit/chromedriver").getAbsolutePath();
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",fullpath);
}

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have made the changes to roll back my versions but it still isnt working, and i have the same 500 internal error :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure your error is due to a wrong version of Guava (see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880). If you have switched to guava 21.0 and still get the error, it means that another version is guava (from tomcat stack) is taking precedence on the guava jar embedded in your war. I do not remember how to do it in Tomcat, but in Wildly and Weblogic for instance you can include a proprietary file (ex: "jboss-deployment-structure.xml") in your WEB-INF in order to ignore/exclude some dependencies (guava in your case) coming by default with your web server stack.

Comment: Change tomcat yo use guava 21.0 (deleted 24 and replaced it with 21 and seems to be happy). But it is still not working, failing with the same error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState